# Activity recognition removed after app is updated

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I use

```
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(googleApiClient, interval, getPendingIntent());
```

to track the user's activity, which works fine. But when I install an update by creating a new build with Android Studio, I stop getting activity updates until I call requestActivityUpdates() again. The same happens when I build a release build and update it with a newer release build.

I would like to continue getting activity updates after the user updates my app in future releases, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a broadcastreceiver that listens for the [ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED) intent.

Copy-pasted from the description:
*Broadcast Action: A new version of an application package has been installed, replacing an existing version that was previously installed.*

Then simply set up the updates again when this intent is received.